# Angular dynamic checkboxes with iteration

Tags: html, css, angularjs, checkbox, iteration

I have a loop delivering a collection of checkboxes which respond as expected by default. I now need to cap the maximum that can be checked at 8 (and retain the full number of checkboxes).

I'm trying to add `ng-model` (and tried `ng-if`) to the class like below but the behavior is incorrect.

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 " ng-hide="vm.resultCount === 0" ng-repeat="np in vm.corporations">
  <div class="Checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.updateCart(np)"/>
      <div class="Checkbox-visible" model="!vm.overEightCorporations">
```

CSS

```
> input:checked + .Checkbox-visible {
    background: #000 url('../images/CheckMark_White.png') center/20px 20px no-repeat;
}

> input:focus + .Checkbox-visible {
}
```

JS

```
vm.overEightCorporations = function () {

        if ($rootScope.cart.length > 7){
            return true;
            toastr.error('You can only set 8 corporations at a time.');
        }
        return false;
        }
    };
```

edit:

Additional JS after responses

```
       vm.updateCart = function (corporation) {

            var i = vm.inCart(corporation.id);
            if (i < 0) {
                $rootScope.cart.push(corporation);
            } else {
                $rootScope.cart.splice(i, 1);
            }

    };
```

Comment: If you don't want to limit your ng-repeat you can probably add check logic to updateCart method. So if a user tries to add more then 8 you will just show toast and won't add new item to the array.

Comment: Thanks @laroslav. I tried modifying the updateCart method and will include that method here. It seems that method is simply an action the occurs as a result of the checkbox. the method itself does nothing to the UI, so I haven't found a way to modify it to affect the check in the box.

Comment: Do you want to hide all check boxes if 8 items are added or disable them? I'm not sure if I understood your task correctly. If so you can add a variable (not a function) vm.overEightCorporations = false; Then check in updateCart if items are more than 8 and set vm.overEightCorporations = true

In HTML you can then use ng-hide="vm.overEightCorporations " where you need.

Comment: I want to disable the checkboxes. I want all checkboxes visible at all times. When a user has clicked 8 I want them to be unable to check any more.

Comment: Then you can use ng-disabled="vm.overEightCorporations" and the rest of logic I described below.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure but your updateCard method removes and adds new items when checkbox selected/deselected. But if you disable all of them then you can't deselect checkbox. Is it expected behavior?

Comment: That is an elegant solution but will not deliver the expected behavior. The user does need to be able to deselect the checkboxes so disable would only work if the unchecked boxes are disabled and the checked boxes are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by appending a "checked" bool to my data object. Had to append object at instantiation then modify it multiple places throughout the code to keep it up-to-date. Issues persisted until I updated ng-click to ng-change which apparently works better with ng-model. I then set the check mark presence simply through the checked bool:

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-change="vm.updateCart(np)" ng-model="np.checked"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply limit your `ng-repeat`s output by your desired value.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 " ng-hide="vm.resultCount === 0" ng-repeat="np in vm.corporations | limitTo: 8">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I should have been more specific. Will update the question. I would like to limit the number of checked boxes, not the total number of boxes themselves.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comments you need to do something similar to it:

```
  vm.updateCart = function (corporation) {
        var i = vm.inCart(corporation.id);
        if (i < 0) {
            $rootScope.cart.push(corporation);
        } else {
            $rootScope.cart.splice(i, 1);
        }

        // if you want to show error message you can do it here
        vm.overEightCorporations = $rootScope.cart.length > 7;

};
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 " ng-hide="vm.resultCount === 0" ng-repeat="np in vm.corporations">
  <div class="Checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.updateCart(np)" ng-class="{ 'checkbox-invisible': vm.overEightCorporations }"/>
      <div class="Checkbox-visible">
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + .checkbox-invisible {
     display:none;
}
```

Comment: That is an elegant solution but will not deliver the expected behavior. The user does need to be able to deselect the checkboxes so disable would only work if the unchecked boxes are disabled and the checked boxes are not.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can try to use CSS for this purpose. So you need to add 'checkbox-invisible' class to checkboxes if 8 is selected. CSS class should check if it's unchecked input and hide it if so. I'm not sure about correctness of my CSS it's just a general idea.